# Changing value in dict with Tkinter

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I have a dict and I need to change it with tkinter.

```
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, Button, mainloop, Entry

master = Tk()
master.geometry ("320x270")

v = StringVar()
e - Entry(master, textvariable=v)
e.pack()
s = v.get()

exit_button = Button(master, text="submit", command=master. destroy)
exit_button.pack(pady=20)

mainloop()

a = {"aaa": s}
print(a)
```

Output

```
{'aaa': ''}
```

I need output with whatever value I will paste in tkinter window

```
{'aaa': 'hello!'}
```

Comment: You're calling `.get()` on your Entry immediately after creating it - before it has actually appeared on the screen.  How could you possibly expect any sort of meaningful value to be retrieved at that point in time?  You need to do the `.get()` *later* - from the Button's `command=` function, perhaps.

Comment: Typo error  `e - Entry` should be `e = Entry`  and `command=master. destroy` should be `command=master.destroy`

Answer (score 1):

If you call `quit` instead of `destroy`, that will cause `mainloop` to exit without destroying the widgets. You can then call `e.get()` or `v.get()` after calling `mainloop` to get the value out of the widget.

The window will automatically get destroyed when there is no more code to run and the event loop is no longer running.

Since you aren't using any of the unique attributes of `StringVar`, you don't need to use it. Also, you can simplify your import by importing the entire tkinter module, and then using the module name when using the widgets.

The following example illustrates all of the above in what I think follows best practices:

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()
master.geometry ("320x270")

e = tk.Entry(master)
e.pack()

exit_button = tk.Button(master, text="submit", command=master.quit)
exit_button.pack(pady=20)

tk.mainloop()
a = {"aaa": e.get()}
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `s` to be set when the button is clicked, to capture the value of the Entry. Not just after the entry has been created, or else it will be empty. Since you need to do all this when the button is clicked, you need to created a function that does this and is called by the button's `command=`.

Here is fully working code:

```
v = StringVar()
e = Entry(master, textvariable=v)
e.pack()

s = None

def onclick():
    global s
    s = v.get()
    master.destroy()

exit_button = Button(master, text="submit", command=onclick)
exit_button.pack(pady=20)

mainloop()

a = {"aaa": s}
print(a)
```